# Debugging Open multiprocessing.Pipe()

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a rather large program with multiple instances of multiprocessing.Pipe() being used. I'll refer to this program as test_pipe. I'm seeing behavior where the
test_pipe program hangs, and I'm trying to determine the reason the program is hanging. I have a suspicion that it's caused by a multiprocessing.Pipe() that
is not being closed properly. As shown below, I use 'ps aux' to retrieve the PID of the test_pipe program while it is hung, and then I use 'lsof -p PID' to list the files that are
still open by the test_pipe program. The test_pipe program lists two open pipes as shown.

```
root@container:~# ps aux
USER        PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         49  1.8  0.2 1020008 40068 ?       Sl   Jun06  19:57 python3 -m test.test_pipe

root@container:~# lsof -p 49
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
test_pipe  21 root    1w  FIFO   0,13      0t0 19391346 pipe
test_pipe  21 root    2w  FIFO   0,13      0t0 19391347 pipe
```

My question is, given the pipe entries in the lsof output, is there any way to match these entries to the multiprocessing.Pipe() instances in my test_pipe program? For example, if
there was a node() function of a multiprocessing Connection, then I could just log each connection's node and that would provide me with enough info on which of the many pipes within the test_pipe program to focus on.

```
from multiprocessing import Pipe, Process
parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
print(f"Parent pipe has node: {parent_conn.node()}")    # node() is NOT a real function, but just used for demonstration purposes
```

node() is not a real function, but is there maybe a way to derive this information from the Connection's fileno() function? I'm also happy to move away from this lsof-based approach if there are other suggestions. My main goal is the quickly narrow in on a problem Pipe given a large program that uses Pipes in many places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls /proc/<pid>/fd` will show all the file descriptors open in a process, and the `fileno()` method will return the number you need to correlate the connection object within the process.

[More info](https://serverfault.com/questions/323810/whats-the-difference-between-lsof-p-pid-wc-l-and-ls-proc-pid-fd-w)